# How do I verify an accesstoken from keycloak based on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, keycloak

I want to verify a retrieved access-token from keycloak.

The targeted application is purely based on Tomcat. Spring Boot framework is not involved and should not be pulled as dependency.

Which options do exist to verify the accesstoken?

Answer (score 0):

First add the dependency into your pom

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>x.x.x</version>
```

Which version you should use depends on two things:

1. the version of the keycloak and
2. the version of the tomcat library you are using.

For our example, a version +16 is sufficient.

Next, you need to configure your KeycloakDeployment.

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = new HttpClientBuilder();
HttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();

AdapterConfig config = new AdapterConfig();
// pointing to your keycloak
config.setAuthServerUrl(url);

JWKPublicKeyLocator locator = new JWKPublicKeyLocator();

KeycloakDeployment deployment = new KeycloakDeployment();
// for sending requests
deployment.setClient(client);
deployment.setAuthServerBaseUrl(config);
// to store your public key
deployment.setPublicKeyLocator(locator);
// how long settings should live in your cache
deployment.setPublicKeyCacheTtl(ttl);
deployment.setRealm(realm);
```

Finally, you are able to check your token.

```
 TokenVerifier<JsonWebToken> verifier = AdapterTokenVerifier
            .createVerifier(token, deployment, true, JsonWebToken.class);
    verifier.verify();
```

What does this code ***actually*** do?

It will dynamically pull the public key from the served auth-server and its realm. The key will be stored in a cache and only gets pulled again if the ttl for the cache has expired.
The delivered token will then be checked against the keycloak deployment and will verify the tokens signature.